# Get specific value from object of arrays ES6 way

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am having a data like

```
var d = [{
  "AD": {
    "name": "Andorra",
    "native": "Andorra",
    "phone": "376",
    "continent": "EU",
    "capital": "Andorra la Vella",
    "currency": "EUR",
  }
}, {
  "AE": {
    "name": "United Arab Emirates",
    "native": "دولة الإمارات العربية المتحدة",
    "phone": "971",
    "continent": "AS",
    "capital": "Abu Dhabi",
    "currency": "AED",
  }
}, {
  "AF": {
    "name": "Afghanistan",
    "native": "افغانستان",
    "phone": "93",
    "continent": "AS",
    "capital": "Kabul",
    "currency": "AFN",
  }
}]
```

and i want to get the name of each object using ES6 higher-order functions without using for or foreach.

i have tried `filter` and `map` but not knowing when to use what

Comment: Name of each object means `Andorra`, `United Arab Emirates` and `Afghanistan`?

Comment: @GrégoryNEUTyes

Comment: This is a horrible structure. Don't use different properties in objects in the same array.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve that using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) as follows:

```js
var d = [{
  "AD": {
    "name": "Andorra",
    "native": "Andorra",
    "phone": "376",
    "continent": "EU",
    "capital": "Andorra la Vella",
    "currency": "EUR",
  }
}, {
  "AE": {
    "name": "United Arab Emirates",
    "native": "دولة الإمارات العربية المتحدة",
    "phone": "971",
    "continent": "AS",
    "capital": "Abu Dhabi",
    "currency": "AED",
  }
}, {
  "AF": {
    "name": "Afghanistan",
    "native": "افغانستان",
    "phone": "93",
    "continent": "AS",
    "capital": "Kabul",
    "currency": "AFN",
  }
}] 

const names = d.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(curr);
  const name = curr[keys[0]].name;
  acc.push(name)
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(names)
```

Comment: Why using a `Array.reduce`, compared to an `Array.map`?

Answer (score -1):

The simply way to achieve that is for me :

```js
var d = [{
  "AD": {
    "name": "Andorra",
    "native": "Andorra",
    "phone": "376",
    "continent": "EU",
    "capital": "Andorra la Vella",
    "currency": "EUR",
  }
}, {
  "AE": {
    "name": "United Arab Emirates",
    "native": "دولة الإمارات العربية المتحدة",
    "phone": "971",
    "continent": "AS",
    "capital": "Abu Dhabi",
    "currency": "AED",
  }
}, {
  "AF": {
    "name": "Afghanistan",
    "native": "افغانستان",
    "phone": "93",
    "continent": "AS",
    "capital": "Kabul",
    "currency": "AFN",
  }
}] 

d.map(item => {
 console.log(Object.keys(item));
})
```

Comment: Sorry that's not what the OP asked for

Answer (score -1):

If there are only one key per object *(AD, AE, AF...)* you can use something like :

```js
const d = [{
  AD: {
    name: 'Andorra',
  }
}, {
  AE: {
    name: 'United Arab Emirates',
  }
}, {
  AF: {
    name: 'Afghanistan',
  },
}];

const reduced = d.map(x => x[Object.keys(x)[0]].name);

console.log(reduced);
```

If there can be multiple key like (AD, AE, ...) you can use something like :

```js
const d = [{
  AD: {
    name: 'Andorra',
  },

  DF: {
    name: 'Paris',
  },
}, {
  AF: {
    name: 'Afghanistan',
  },
}];

const reduced = d.reduce((tmp, x) => [
  ...tmp,
  
  ...Object.values(x).map(y => y.name),
], []);

console.log(reduced);
```